# Common Table Expression print all dates between provided Start and End dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I want to write query, Common Table Expression Statement to print all dates between provided Start and End dates?

for Example:
startDate: 15-JAN-2014
Enddate:  15-Feb-2014

Comment: You need to have some `Days` table for this.

Comment: Yes days and month also

Comment: for example date is 15-jan-2013 to 15-April-2013 then i want to show dates between this

Comment: This can easily be done with php, but in order to do this with sql only, you need to have additional table, that stores days

Comment: can we do this on run time? without sql table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @mindate DATETIME
DECLARE @maxdate DATETIME
DECLARE @diff INT
SET @maxdate = '2014-02-15'
SET @mindate = '2014-01-15'

SET @diff = DATEDIFF(DAY,  @mindate,@maxdate)
;WITH cte(dt,level)
AS
(
    SELECT  @mindate AS dt, 0 AS level 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(day,1,cte.dt),level + 1 from cte WHERE level < @diff
)
SELECT dt FROM cte
option (maxrecursion 32767)
```

**Option maxrecursion is required if the start and end dates are more than 100 days apart**

check the query at SQLFiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fd09f/10

Answer (score 2):

```
 Declare @start date='2014-01-15' 
 Declare @Enddate date='2014-02-15' 
 ;with CTE as
 (select @start dates
 union all
 select DATEADD(day,1,dates) from cte where dates<@Enddate

 )
 select * from cte
```